# SKSpriteNode Overlay not been showed

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to make a overlay in my SpriteKit game.

```
    let overlay = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: self.size)
    overlay.alpha = 0.3
    self.addChild(overlay)
```

The Overlay is not been shown on the screen, what is wrong?

Comment: have you tried increasing the aplha to confirm? Also set the zPosition to a higher value.

Comment: overlay.zPosition = 1, Did the trick... Thanks...

Comment: Great. Have added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `zPosition` to a higher value to ensure it is drawn above sprites with a lower zPosition value.

For overlays, an arbitrary high value can be used to ensure it is drawn above all other sprites.

```
node.zPosition = 100;
```

You can read more about zPosition [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/zPosition).